# Qt FullScreen on Startup

Tags: c++, macos, qt, fullscreen

I want to start an application on fullscreen (MacOS 10.8.x, Qt 5.1.1, C++) depending on the settings:

main.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.showFullScreen();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The settings comportment is perfect, works like a charm. But `this->showFullScreen()` does something very ugly :

1. Display the window in fullscreen
2. Display the window in normal size in the center
3. Scale the window to fullscreen

How to avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried calling setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowFullScreen | Qt::Customize) ?

Comment: @Merlin069 `Qt::Customize` seems to be unknown by Qt and if I remove it, the compilation fail with a worst message

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, that should be Qt::CustomizeWindowHint

Comment: @Merlin069 `error: no viable conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'Qt::WindowFlags' (aka 'QFlags<Qt::WindowType>')`

Comment: Try to call showFullScreen not in the constructor but afterwards (in main() or wherever the mainwindow is created)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld don't work either

Comment: @Samoth is it not maximize? For me in constructor `this->showMaximized();` is working well. and yes if you are calling showFullScreen in constructor don't call show in main. it is causing the sequence point 1 and 2 in your ugly display.

Comment: If you're getting the no viable conversion error, can you show the code that you're calling?

Comment: @Tab this : `this->showMaximized();` has not the same effect than `this->showFullScreen();`

Comment: @Merlin069 I did a better snippet, same issue...

Comment: Have you tried printing out the window states to see what the window thinks it's doing?

Comment: @Merlin069 I've surrounded `ui->setupUi(this);` and `w.showFullScreen();` with windowState(), before showFullScreen and around setupUI the flags are empty (`QFlags()`) after showFullScreen it goes `QFlags(0x4)` still have no clue...

Comment: Ok, according to the docs, this should work if you call it before show: w->setWindowState(w->windowState() & Qt::WindowFullScreen);

Comment: @Merlin069 with the `&` it doesn't work, with `|` it follow the same process, first show the window minimized then it goes FS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40711/discussion-between-merlin069-and-samoth)

Comment: Try to `hide()` the window before going to fullscreen.

Comment: Is your case same as this: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-21607 ?

Comment: @hyde Unfortunate not...

Comment: Have you tried anything else? You should try before expecting others to do it for you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I already faced this problem and a very nice solution was to delay the fullscreen switch by one second (using a *QTimer*):

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(showFullScreen()));
```

Answer (score 29):

use the following if you want to have the app open as **maximized** window:

```
Mainwindow w;
w.setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
w.show();
```

use the following if you want to have the app open as **fullscreen** window:

```
Mainwindow w;
w.setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
w.show();
```

Comment: Succinct alternatives are `w.showMaximized()` and `w.showFullScreen()`.

Answer (score 13):

You can try `QMainWindow::showFullScreen()` in the constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMainWindow::showFullScreen();
}
```

Comment: Where should I add this part? could you clarify more? thanks

Comment: @Yamur His code referenced the `ui->setupUi()` so it would be in the constructor. I updated the answer accordingly to make it clear, especially because I think this is the best (cleanest) solution.

Answer (score 7):

QWidget states should help you. Follow this Qt-documentation: [QWidget::setWindowState](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#setWindowState).

Way to put app into fullscreen:

```
MainWindow w;    
w.setWindowState(w.windowState() ^ Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

Thanks

Comment: Works like a charm. Though I don't use any of that ^ and just do `this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen)` inside the constructor of my MainWindow class and it starts fullscreen instantly. The problem with using a QTimer is that even if you set it to 1 you can still see how the window maximizes so that it can go to fullscreen, which doesn't look that good to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call `showFullScreen()` in `showEvent()`. I can't check it with Qt 5.1.1 currently but it worked quite well with 4.8.x

Comment: @Thomas It's more likely that the answer caused your question to be bumped and thus someone else downvoting - someone who answers would most likely have cast their vote _before_ bothering to answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a QWidget as my main window, but I got it to work perfectly with this simple line:

```
this->showMaximized();
```

Upon running, it appeared filling the entire screen immediately and smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just delay the Fullscreen switch by 1 second with a Qtimer. It's not the best solution, but it does fix the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way today, it seems best for me until now.. I tried many other solutions nothing worked.

What I do is;

- getting available screen resolution clearly.
- resizing the window simply before showinf window
- showing the window normally

Keep in mind, if you do `showWindow()` before setting the window resize, and if you have a scene in main program then the scroll will not be on center because of resize. Also the window may not be positioned correctly. So firstly `setFixedSize()` and `ShowNormal()` as below..

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  WhateverMainWindowClass *w = new WhateverMainWindowClass();

/////////////////////////

  QRect screenGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
  w->resize(screenGeometry.width(), screenGeometry.height());
  w->showNormal();

/////////////////////////

  return app.exec();
}
```

in addition you can make `setFixedSize()` instead of `resize()`, just with exactly same way, so then the size will be static, no one can change it.

Comment: availableGeometry() is depreciated now. just use w.showFullscreen()